# Windows apps crashes randomly (diagnosis)

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, virtual-memory

Recently I am experiencing random crashes on windows and seemingly not related to specific apps and without a blue-screen, some give strange errors and seem like OS-related issues. sometimes I see screen flashes or disturbed UIs which indicates a VGA problem but I have the latest verified intel VGA driver which works for everyone else according to the related forums.

Some forums suggested going through the logs I can find with the Windows Event Viewer. I found a LOT of errors, "Application Error", "Application Hang" and things like these, all have random reasons the most interesting common part is this one:

```
Exception code: 0xe0000008
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll
```

full log:

```
Faulting application name: chrome.exe, version: 93.0.4577.63, time stamp: 0x612932e3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1202, time stamp: 0xc9db1934
Exception code: 0xe0000008
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034f99
Faulting process id: 0x3bac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7a8209a121651
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 23089725-145b-4ee3-8a62-ff03978688cc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Are any problems found? Is Windows fully updated?

Comment: @harrymc it is a newly set up pc and up-to-date. I again run these and found no problems, the issue was I disabled the Virtual Memory mistakenly. I explained in my own Answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of windows 7/8/10 related "random crashes", on SuperUser, Microsoft forums, Reddit, many other PC or OS-related forums on the internet.

The reasons for all of them could be broken down into these topics:

### Application-specific problems:

mostly solved by finding the root cause and fixing through changing settings, installing other software, applying external manipulations, workarounds, etc...

### OS-related problems:

If it is happening for non-related applications and you can test to see if you change the app you still get those errors, it's probably OS related, and if it is coming with a BSOD (blue-screen) it's most probably a **driver software related issue**, and least probably **hardware issues**. And if it is **without a BSOD** it's either a **VGA fault issue** or a **Memory fault issue**.

For VGA issues you can confirm if other people have the same problems with the same **VGA drivers** installed and you can conclude what to do next from that answer, like upgrading or even downgrading the driver, install an alternative driver, make configurations on the system settings, VGA apps or even in BIOS.

For memory problems, usually, if the problem is as simple as low physical memory you will receive relevant errors which you can understand you need to make RAM upgrades but if you have enough physical memory (free RAM in Tak Manager or Resource Monitor) and you eliminated VGA issues too then the only remaining reason is related to the shortage of Virtual Memory!

This is most probably because **Virtual Memory (aka Page File)** is disabled or customized to a lower than required value, which people tend to do because of low storage space issues to save some more storage space. Just re-enable it by choosing the option "System managed size" or a custom high enough value in your main system drive, and see if the crashes are gone or not.

Which in my case they did! And to be honest, I disabled my Virtual Memory not to save storage space because I thought since I have enough free RAM, it's more performant if the system only use that instead of a Virtual which is limited by the slower speed of the storage device, and I disable it so Windows does not even try to do that, but it seems sometimes it had to (I don't know why) and if it couldn't it produced errors.

Since it sounds stupid a little, it is the hardest to find (also because errors are not giving helpful information). And I saw many crash questions without an answer on the internet which seemed to me for the same reason, and since I can't go around the internet and answer them all, I wrote in here.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm such a crash with MS Teams, when I had limited my page file to 10GB, exactly as Unicornist said: to save disc space, as I was running low on C:,

Faulting application name: Teams.exe, version: 1.5.0.17656, time stamp: 0x6290b64e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1826, time stamp: 0x299341e8
Exception code: 0xe0000008
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034fd9
Faulting process id: 0x7b8c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1138368)